# Minecraft command to induce hunger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to be hungry for a video I'm making. Are there any commands to make me hungry?

Answer (score 1):

do this :)

> /effect @p minecraft:hunger 2 201

Answer (score 0):

#### There are no commands to make you hungry, only commands to cause effects

Using the command `/effect <your username> 17 <time in seconds>` you can cause the hunger effect, which rapidly drains your food bar.

Also, you can sprint and *jump* to lose hunger points faster also (not as fast though)